# Difference between set, \set and \pset in psql

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I get a little confused some times when working with `psql` between when to use a `set` vs. `\set` vs. `\pset`.  I think that:

- `set` is for session variables on my connection to the db. For example `SET ROLE dba`;
- `\set` is for local variables for this psql session. For example `\set time 'select current_timestamp'`
- `\pset` is for psql settings for this psql session. For example `'\pset border 2'`

But, I've never found what I thought was a good explanation of each. Are my assumptions above correct?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4

Comment: `set` is a SQL command and can be used from any SQL client. `\set` and `\pset` can only be used with `psql`

Comment: It's unfortunate that `\set` wasn't named `\varset` or something.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Basically correct. The important difference is that `SET` is an SQL command while the other two are psql meta-commands - indicated by the leading `\`.

[`SET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html) is an SQL command to change run-time parameters. It is executed on the server and has nothing to do with psql per se.

[`\set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is a psql meta-command:

> Sets the psql variable name to value [...]

> Note: This command is unrelated to the SQL command `SET`.

[`\pset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) is another psql meta-command:

> This command sets options affecting the output of query result tables

Comment: To make it easier to remember, think of the P in \pset as "print".  pset values are ones that change how psql prints information out to you.  \set changes other types of psql configuration.