# Execute \set command with function as value

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid, psql

In one of my SQL scripts for PostgreSQL I want to declare a value so that I can use it in several places in the rest of the script.

Here is what I did based on the [following thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593908/difference-between-set-set-and-pset-in-psql) :

```
\set cat_id uuid_generate_v4()
insert into categories (id, name) values (:cat_id, 'Category 1')
insert into other_table (id, category_id) values (uuid_generate_v4(), :cat_id)
```

The problem is that the variable `cat_id` does not take the value once for all. It just replaces `:cat_id` by `uuid_generate_v4()`. Therefore, the value is not the same in the two insert queries.

How can I do to give `cat_id` the value of the execution of the function ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `:cat_id` contains `uuid_generate_v4()`, you're using it as a macro. `\set` variables in psql can be used both as macros and as variables.

> *Q: How can I do to give cat_id the value of the execution of the function
>   ?*

```
select uuid_generate_v4() as cat_id \gset
```

Doc:

> **\gset [ prefix ]**
>       Sends the current query input buffer to the server and stores the query's output into
>       psql variables (see Variables). The query to be executed must return exactly one row.
>       Each column of the row is stored into a separate variable, named the same as the column.

Note that afterwards to inject it into a statement, the syntax to use is `:'cat_id'` so that it gets properly quoted as a literal.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an anonymous `DO` block with a variable initialized with a new UUID.

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
  cat_id uuid = uuid_generate_v4();
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO categories
              (id,
               name)
              VALUES (cat_id,
                      'Category 1');
  INSERT INTO other_table
              (id,
               category_id)
              VALUES (uuid_generate_v4(),
                      cat_id),
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLpgSQL;
```